# CRM Web Resource Linker/Publisher: Connection Failed to CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, visual-studio-addins, dynamics-crm-online

I am try to use the visual studio add-in "CRM 2011 Web Resource Linker/Publisher" from http://webresourcelinker.codeplex.com/.

When connecting to CRM 2013 Online, I get this error `"Connection failed: There is an error in XML document(5, 5)"`

I have checked Discovery Url, Username, Password, Unique Org Name.

Could you tell me what's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to resolve it, but still don't know the root cause. Here the steps:

1. Go to path: `C:\Users\<current user>\LiveDeviceID`
2. Delete the `LiveDevice.xml`
3. Try to connect from the application.
4. If this doesn’t solve the error, follow steps 1 and 2, reboot and try connecting from the application.

This should solve the problem.

Reference: http://skynetr.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/crm-2011-error-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-5-5/